# Incorrect syntax near 'FK_dbo.SalesOrderLineTasks_dbo.Events_Event_ID'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I try and run

```
alter table salesorderlinetasks drop constraint 
'FK_dbo.SalesOrderLineTasks_dbo.Events_Event_ID'
```

this command in Sql Server Management Studio, I get an error.

> Incorrect syntax near 'FK_dbo.SalesOrderLineTasks_dbo.Events_Event_ID'.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It should contain double quotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use *no* quotes:

```
alter table salesorderlinetasks drop constraint 
  FK_dbo.SalesOrderLineTasks_dbo.Events_Event_ID
```

Quotes delimit literal text, but `alter` requires an entity (which is not a text string but a plain entity name).

Comment: Running the above produces an error "Incorrect syntax near '.'

Comment: @kirsteng what is the exact SQL you executed?

Comment: alter table salesorderlinetasks drop constraint  FK_dbo.SalesOrderLineTasks_dbo.Events_Event_ID

Comment: @kirsteng so your table name and constraint name are exactly the same as the ones in this question? I don't think so. Use *your* table and constraint names instead. ie `alter table <myTableName> drop constraint <myConstraintName>`

Comment: I can repeat the issue with other tables the problem is the constraint name contains a full stop.